# Haskell @ operator confusion

Tags: haskell

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat 
       deriving (Eq, Show)

-- Add two Natural number
addNat :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat 
addNat Zero Zero         = Zero
addNat Zero n@(Succ _)   = n
addNat n@(Succ _) Zero   = n
addNat (Succ x) (Succ y) = Succ (Succ (addNat x y))
```

I am confuse about the @ operator in Haskell function.

I am wondering what does `addNat Zero n@(Succ _)   = n` means?

Does it mean that `addNat Zero Succ b = Succ b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `name` is a variable name, and `pat` is a pattern, then `name@pat` is a pattern that matches exactly when `pat` does, and also binds `name` to the value that matched `pat`. So:

```
addNat n@(Succ _) Zero = n
```

says "if the first argument is a `Succ` and the second is a `Zero`, then return the first argument".

Comment: so, it is equivalent as `addNat (Succ n) Zero = Succ n`?

Comment: @wrek It is semantically equivalent, though GHC and other compilers may do something slightly different with that code. Specifically, with `addNat n@(Succ _) Zero = n`, GHC will not allocate a new `Nat`, whereas with `addNat (Succ n) Zero = Succ n`, GHC may (especially at low optimization levels) destruct the first argument and construct a *new* `Nat` with the same meaning as the old one.